# Web API Defining routes to controllers asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I'm beginner on stack overflow and in ASP.NET in general but I'll try to make my point clear here.

I'm developping a Web API in VB.NET but I'm stuck when I try to define routes.

I have for example these functions :

```
Public Function GetAllInformations() As IEnumerable(Of cl_information)

    'return all informations

End Function

Public Function GetInformations(p_id As Int16) As IHttpActionResult

    'return a specific informations

End Function

Public Function PutInformation(p_information As cl_information) As IHttpActionResult

    'return the http statuscode depending on the update of the information

End Function

Public Function PostInformation(p_information As cl_information) As IHttpActionResult

    'return the http statuscode depending on the post of the information

End Function
```

When I try this controller, using postman, I firsty check the GET method for the URI : /api/informations. The GetAllInformations() method is correctly triggered.
But when I try the GET method for a specific information item, on this kind of URI : /api/informations/i , the GetAllInformations() is also triggered.

I've got these informations from the event journal in visual studio :

```
"data": {
"baseType": "RequestData",
"baseData": {
  "ver": 2,
  "id": "12785441767974844366",
  "name": "GET informations [id]",
  "startTime": "2016-05-12T08:56:49.4044704+02:00",
  "duration": "00:00:04.1740006",
  "success": true,
  "responseCode": "200",
  "url": "http://localhost:51651/api/informations/i",
  "httpMethod": "GET",
  "properties": {
    "DeveloperMode": "true"
  }
}
```

I don't know why the request is not correctly routing to my GetInformations(p_id As Int16) function. Could you help me here please ?

FYI : I have this basic routes configuration :

```
Public Module WebApiConfig
Public Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
    ' Configuration et services API Web

    ' Itinéraires de l'API Web
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub


End Module
```

EDIT :

I tried to implement a method to handle both cases, with an optional argument, but the parameter isn't detected, event if I test the URI : /api/informations/i

```
        Public Function GetInformations(Optional p_id As Int16 = 0) As IHttpActionResult

        If p_id = 0 Then

            'return all informations

        End If

            'return a specific information

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a day and a half on this, my mind is blowing but I finally found the problem.

I was using a wrong parameter name :

```
Public Function GetInformations(p_id As Int16) As IHttpActionResult
```

So I changed it by :

```
Public Function GetInformations(id As Int16) As IHttpActionResult
```

and it's working.

Comment: You could have also changed your route to be /{p_id} instead of {id}.